# PWA Workbox third party images not working

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am working with `workbox PWA`.

The problem: I have cached images from a third party url.

What happens: it caches some images and some images did not cache and I got an error.

> TypeError: failed to fetch.

I do not understand why this happened while I am using same url and it does not fecth all images.

- https://third-party-url/stage.jpg [failed to fetch]
- https://third-party-url/icon_youtube.png [fetch-images]

Comment: As what I have observed in your statement, you are trying to use files from a different origin or source. Basically there is a special handling in Workbox that I think you need to know. Try to check [Cross-Origin Requests and Opaque Responses](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have read this cross origin article and apply the same. When I used <link crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/path/to/style.css"> corssorigin attribute then I become errors access-control-cors-origin Erros